# in angularjs code the selsct box is not worked correctly.but all filter is worked.what i do

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the code has small  mistakes.but i run in firefox error not displayed correctly.so what i do.i want to search by selection field click.
 the code has small  mistakes.but i run in firefox error not displayed correctly.so what i do.i want to search by selection field click.
 the code has small  mistakes.but i run in firefox error not displayed correctly.so what i do.i want to search by selection field click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="App">

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var iApp = angular.module("App", []);
    iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {
      return function(items, input) {
        var filtered = [];
        if (input === undefined || input === '') {
          console.log(items);
          return items;
        }
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
          if (item.name.indexOf(input) == 0 || item.city.indexOf(input) == 0 || item.state.indexOf(input) === 0) {
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        });
        return filtered;
      };
    });
    iApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, $filter) {
      $scope.array = [{
        name: "BALA",
        city: "KOVAI",
        state: "TAMILNADU"
      }, {
        name: "ARUN",
        city: "THRISSUR",
        state: "KERALA"
      }, {
        name: "ZEE",
        city: "TIRUPATHI",
        state: "ANDHRA"
      }, {
        name: "KARAN",
        city: "THARAVI",
        state: "MUMBAI"
      }, {
        name: "SINGH",
        city: "MOHALIT",
        state: "PUNJAB"
      }];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="TestController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="all" PLACEHOLDER="FOR ALL" />

  <select ng-model="filter">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="state">State</option>
  </select>


  <table>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <TR ng-repeat="arr in array |myfilter:all">
      <TD>{{ arr.name }}</TD>
      <TD>{{arr.city}}</TD>
      <TD>{{arr.state}}</TD>
    </TR>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do not use angular.min.js when developing, you get crappy errors. .min.js is for production. change it to the full angular and then check the errors

Comment: what i do for select click function